# values of items are different after scroll the second time in RecyclerView

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I am listing items  that have a main picture and four thumb images below, to get them I first call to parsequery, after that they are displayed with the url . When I Scroll the first time everything looks good, but after first scrolling, if I have just two thumb images in any item, the consecuent thumbs 3 and 4 are displaying the thumb images of the first item. Here is the code, I've simplified it a litle

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(final VersionViewHolder versionViewHolder, final int i) {

      final Post itPost = items.get(i);

      versionViewHolder.itemView.setTag(itPost);

      ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Images");
      query.whereEqualTo("postid", itPost.getIdPost());
      query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
      query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject> () {
        @Override
        public void done(final List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
          if(e == null) {

            for(int o = 0; o < objects.size(); o++) {

              if(o == 0) {
                ImageUtil.displayImage(versionViewHolder.mainImg, objects.get(o).getString("url"), null);
              } else if(o == 1) {
                ImageUtil.displayImage(versionViewHolder.imgThumb, objects.get(o).getString("url"), null);
              } else if(o == 2) {
                ImageUtil.displayImage(versionViewHolder.imgThumb2, objects.get(o).getString("url"), null);
              } else if(o == 3) {
                ImageUtil.displayImage(versionViewHolder.imgThumb3, objects.get(o).getString("url"), null);
              } else if(o == 4) {

                ImageUtil.displayImage(versionViewHolder.imgThumb4, objects.get(o).getString("url"), null);

                versionViewHolder.imgThumb4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                    //alertGallery(,versionViewHolder.itemView);
                  }

                });
              } else if(o <= 5) {

                String num = "" + o;
                versionViewHolder.txtContadorImagenes.setText("+ ");

                //TODO 
              }

            }

          }

        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from running the Parse query every time the `onBindViewHolder()` method is called and using the for loop.

You can also simplify the Parse table you are using. I am assuming that you wanted for each item, 1 main image and 4 thumbnails. Hence each `ParseObject` representing 1 item should contain the urls to the main image and the 4 thumbnails. You should not create a `ParseObject` for each url. 1 `ParseObject` = 1 item in the RecyclerView :)

1. In Parse, rename `url` to `urlMain` and create the columns for the four thumbnails `urlThumb1`, `urlThumb2`, `urlThumb3` and `urlThumb4` with datatype String.
2. Move your query outside the `onBindViewHolder()` method, say for instance to the `onCreate()` method of your Activity.
3. In the `done()` callback of the Parse query, pass the query results list `objects` to your adapter and set the adapter on your RecyclerView.
4. In `onBindViewHolder()` remove the for loop and use `displayImage` based on the ParseObject selected, determined by the position (of the item within the adapter's data set).

Code would look like:

- in your activity and `onCreate()`:

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          // execute the parseQuery
          ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Images");
          query.whereEqualTo("postid", itPost.getIdPost());
          query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
          query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject> () {
              @Override
              public void done(final List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                  if(e == null) {
                      // if no ParseException, pass the objects list to the adapter
                      YourAdapter yourAdapter = new YourAdapter(objects);
                      // set the adapter
                      yourRecyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
                  }
              }
          }

      ...

      }
  }
  ```
- in your adapter

  ```
  public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourViewHolder> {
      private List<ParseObject> list;

      public YourAdapter(List<ParseObject> objects) {
          list = objects;
      }

      ...

      // in the onBindViewHolder method, set the image based on the position
      @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(YourViewHolder holder, int position) {
          ParseObject currentObj = list.get(position);

          ImageUtil.displayImage(holder.mainImg, currentObj.getString("urlMain"), null);
          ImageUtil.displayImage(holder.imgThumb, currentObj.getString("urlThumb1"), null);
          ImageUtil.displayImage(holder.imgThumb2, currentObj.getString("urlThumb2"), null);
          ImageUtil.displayImage(holder.imgThumb3, currentObj.getString("urlThumb3"), null);
          ImageUtil.displayImage(holder.imgThumb4, currentObj.getString("urlThumb4"), null);

          holder.imgThumb4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  //alertGallery(,versionViewHolder.itemView);
              }
      }
  }
  ```

Hopefully this helps, comment below if that is not what you wanted or have questions!

Comment: Yes , thats correct  as you describe bastien, and is the correct way. But I did in this way  because I have two class, one is to Post, and another to Images, Post is being to the adapter as you can see in the following code : https://codeshare.io/znar7 , If you can help  , I am trying to get the Images url to each post, with a join, a relational  one to many, Images class has a field called randomposid wich is the same in Post class in field postid,I did not find the correct way to make Relational query with Parse